# PHP Make to array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to print the results of search result in the array. until now that I can do is print out the plain search results.

I use this code to print serch :

```
$response = json_decode($connection->response['response'],true);
$tweet_data = $response['statuses']; 
$tweet_stream = '';     
    foreach($tweet_data as $tweet) {
        $tweet_stream .= $tweet['text'] . '<br/>';
        }           
    print $tweet_stream;
```

will give print result like :

```
Tweet1
Tweet2
....
TweetN
```

How to change the results in the array?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: or you can use print_r($tweet_data) while your $tweet_data is an array already.so no need foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking

```
$response = json_decode($connection->response['response'],true);
$tweet_data = $response['statuses']; 
$tweet_stream_arr = array();
foreach($tweet_data as $tweet) {
  $tweet_stream_arr[] = $tweet['text'];
}           
print_r($tweet_stream_arr);
```

---

You can do this a little easier with [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) though

```
$tweet_stream_text = array_map(function($tweet) {
  return $tweet['text'];
}, $tweet_data);

print_r($tweet_stream_text);
```

**Note** this requires PHP >= 5.3

Comment: Hi naomik, i get error unexpected T_VARIABLE in print_r $tweet_stream_arr; but I do not forget the semicolon.